# Magento 2. Add ui-form elements dynamically (at Admin area)

Tags: javascript, forms, knockout.js, magento2

We have a ui-form at Admin area, which should implement the following behavior: "on product category select, show filterable product attributes with possible values (as multi-selects)".

Product categories are displayed as drop-down list.
There is a controller, which retrieves attributes with values for a provided category id.

How to join these together so on "Category select" the form gets several multi-selects added below?

General problem. To create a ui-form in admin, xml form fields are defined. However, in this case, these field names are not known in advance - we do not know what are the filters available for a particular category, neither we know the multi-select values.
As an attempt for solution, we added a javascript to the form, which ajax-called a controller on category drop-down change and it returned the required data, but how to add new form fields to an already created form, then?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also trying to add UI-components to an admin form generated with PHP

Answer (score 0):

First, find out the layout of this page. Then, overwrite this on your module by adding custom js to it. There you can handle this case by adding js functions.
If I am not correct, please add the screenshot of your dropdown & multi-select.